# How to constrain ordinary kriging weights to sum to 1 in R

Tags: r, weights, geostatistics, kriging

I need to perform ordinary kriging on a dataset and I understand that I need the weights to sum to 1, I just don't understand how to set that up properly. For example, my covariance function is  C(h) = 10 exp(−3h/10 ), and the kriging distance is 1 unit to each of the 2 observed points I have. So, before making the weights sum to 1, the 2 weights would be 0.4783139. I'm not sure how to set up this equation differently to make them sum to 1. I know the weights will equal 0.5, I just don't know how to properly derive that.

Comment: It's a constrained optimization.  Use a Lagrange multiplier.